# Square Spin #2: Climb the Mountain!

Tags: no-computers, optimization, grid-deduction

Square Spin History: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/square-spin-1-sun-and-moon)>#2

---

> ### New Rules
>
> ---
>
> This puzzle introduces two new square types:
>
> - Unmovable squares (Un)
> - Replaceable squares (Re)
>
> Plus the concept of ambiguity!
>
> **Ambiguity of squares**
>
> Certain square types are defined as being **ambiguous**. When a square type is ambiguous, it can *only be seen* in the initial image of the problem! This *does not* mean that it only exists for the first move, ambiguous squares exist throughout the *whole* problem! Ambiguous squares will appear to be regular coloured squares in the desired image.
>
> **Unmovable squares**
>
> These squares contain a cross and they *prohibit* all moves that end up displacing it from its position.
>
> Here is an example of an invalid move
> [image: Showing an incorrect example on what looks like a snake]
> However, this is a perfectly valid move
> [image: What looks like a turbine spinning on an axis]
>
> **Replaceable squares**
>
> This type of square contains a circle and it has a fairly complicated condition attached to it. It *prohibits* all moves that *don't* replace it with the same colour of square when the move changes its position upon completion. Oh, and this square type is **ambiguous**!
>
> Here is an example of a valid move
> [image: Three circles spinning]
> There are some pitfalls to be aware of! For example, this requires *two* moves
> [image: Image of a circle being chased]
>
> ### Recap of Previous Rules
>
> ---
>
> - **Basic rules** from [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/square-spin-1-sun-and-moon)

### Problem #2: Climb the Mountain!

---

Two mountain climbers scaled a tall and dangerous rocky mountain using teamwork and wits. They had set up a camera to take photos of the climb at regular intervals however, the camera corrupted all of the photos except for two. Luckily the two photos had caught the start and end of their journey. Can you figure out what happened along their journey?
[image: Can you find out how they scaled the mountain]
Get a 7x7 grid to work with [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63NMR.png) or alternatively get a 7x14 grid [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UevcV.png)

Comment: "no-computers" is really meant to be "no-brute-force" since I can't imagine solving this without some sort of visual aid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm at **11** now, by using the circle on the right you can make your life a *little* easier.
>
>
> [image]
>
>
>  **ORIGINAL POST:** I'm at **12**.  The big 4x4 spin seems unavoidable, and everything else is in service to it.  Feels like everything is as efficient as it can be, but I wouldn't be surprised if I missed something... nothing I did feels overly clever, and I'd expect something like that in a particularly crafted puzzle such as this.  The gray circle on the right does nothing and that gives me pause.
>
>
> [image]

Comment: Yep! Smoother second time around :). Those days are in the past now

Comment: @Adam thanks I needed a little confidence boost (I've given some bad answers lately).  These puzzles were fun.  I think I preferred the simplicity of the first one, but this one had it's charms.  I worry you scared some people off with adding too many new rules at once, but I've been guilty of that.

Comment: I quickly realised after making the #1 that these puzzles wouldn't have a future if I didn't add something. I struggled trying to make another #1!  It was also unfortunate when I realised that I could only introduce Un and Re squares at the same time or else the puzzle wouldn't be fun. Hopefully your answer can act as a great example to anyone in the future if I make any more! P. s. I do plan to add more rules but I'm trying my best to ease everyone into it!

Answer (score 1):

A <s>naive</s> approach somehow manages to get them up the mountain in

> <s>24 21 19 15</s> **14** moves:
>  [image]
>  (black are the fixed rocks, darker squares are replaceable, lighter squares are the normal ones)

Comment: Good attempt and nice visualisation! The climbers took a *way* more optimised route though. Think about strategy, is there a way to cut out a lot of work?

Comment: Shaved off several moves since then, how close am I to your solution?

Comment: You are definitely closer but you still have a bit to go! Try looking at the problem from a different perspective...

Comment: We have similar ideas on how to tackle this one, though the edit I'm looking at has errors.  Step 4 requires a spin that is out-of-bounds, and the big spin in step 7 and 8 isn't possible because the replacement squares want to spin in opposite directions.