# Square Spin #3: Hickory Dickory Dock

Tags: no-computers, optimization, grid-deduction

Square Spin History: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/square-spin-1-sun-and-moon)>[#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/square-spin-2-climb-the-mountain)>#3

---

> ### Recap of the Rules
>
> ---
>
> - **Basic rules** from [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/square-spin-1-sun-and-moon)
> - **Ambiguity, Un and Re squares** from [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/square-spin-2-climb-the-mountain)

### Problem #3: Hickory Dickory Dock

---

The mouse ran up the clock.

...but how did it run up the clock?

> **Special requirement**
>
> ---
>
> You cannot move any square that is currently below the mouse when the move doesn't include the mouse

[image: Can you figure out how the mouse ran up the clock]
Get a 7x11 grid to work with [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhXIt.png)

**Hint 1**

> Even although ambiguity makes this problem look messy, there are many deductions that can easily be made by comparing the two images!

**Hint 2**

> The mouse moves upward at an average rate of one square per move!

Comment: By the way, you never actually asked a question.  I assume we are doing what we did in question 1, but not everybody jumps in on the first puzzle in a series.

Comment: @DarkThunder ok, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your hint tells me I have the right number of moves, and with some quick rearranging after being informed I missed a rule, this should be right:
>
>
> [image]

Comment: You are very close but... "You cannot move any square that is currently below the mouse when the move doesn't include the mouse".

Comment: Ahhh okay that explains why it didn't feel constrained at the end.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer. However you accidentally got the Re squares in images 9 and 10 in the wrong places

Comment: @Adam yeah I excel at making mistakes