# Square Spin #4: Rude Awakening

Tags: no-computers, optimization, grid-deduction

Square Spin History: [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/square-spin-1-sun-and-moon)>[#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/square-spin-2-climb-the-mountain)>[#3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85921/square-spin-3-hickory-dickory-dock)>#4

---

> ### New Rule
>
> ---
>
> This puzzle introduces a new square type:
>
> - Lonely squares (Ly)
>
> **Lonely squares**
>
> This type of square contains a box and it is the *exact* opposite of the Re square type. All moves where an Ly is replaced by a square of equal colour upon completion is *prohibited*. This square type is also **ambiguous** just like the Re!
>
> For example this move is valid
> [image: A T shape spinning]
> However, the tricky logic of this square makes this seemingly intuitive move invalid...
> [image: Miniature clock wind]
> ...because it cannot even replace itself!
>
> ### Recap of Previous Rules
>
> ---
>
> - **Basic rules** from [#1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81682/square-spin-1-sun-and-moon)
> - **Ambiguity, Un and Re squares** from [#2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85594/square-spin-2-climb-the-mountain)

### Problem #4: Rude Awakening

---

By the time you see this puzzle I'll be asleep. Making rules is exhausting! Please wake me up when you've found the answer to this puzzle... by finding the answer - to this puzzle. ZZZZZZZzzzzzzzz...
[image]
Get a 7x7 grid to work with [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63NMR.png)

**Hint**

> The tables have turned!

Comment: Due to the nature of this puzzle I expect a slightly more detailed answer than just the solution. Also, I might soon take a break from these puzzles for a while and focus on other types of puzzles!

Comment: If my bounty runs out I'll answer this, but I'd feel better if more people tried it.  It's at least as good as the first puzzle was... also no idea if I'm at the optimal point yet.

Comment: @DarkThunder you most likely are at the optimal point. Thanks for the bounty btw

Comment: Would be neat if somebody made this kind of game into an app!

Comment: @Parseltongue Thanks! Actually, I programmed a basic tool which helps me build these puzzles and save them as images as well as perform rotations. The code underlying the logic of the game is surprisingly simple. I might consider publishing the tool (in some form) in the future so that the solving side is just as natural as the creation side!

Comment: Oh, you should share the tool!  I'm having a hard time simulating it all in my head, and I wonder how other people solve it

Comment: @Parseltongue I use excel.  When I change the column widths to "2.3" the cells become very nearly square.  Changing the color of individual cells is a little time-consuming but with copy-pasting it goes quick enough.  That's not to say I wouldn't be interested in an app, this strikes me as a fun little time-waster and I bet you could do alright... hardest part would be thinking up interesting puzzles again and again.

Comment: I'd be curious in dynamically generating the puzzles... it's perhaps a more interesting puzzle designing an algorithm that can convert any one configuration to another in the minimum number of steps.

Comment: @Parseltongue That would work really well for #2 and #3 type puzzles since I specifically designed them around predetermined moves. For #1 type puzzles it would be very complex because at that point it becomes a bit like chess. Lots of potential for many programming and puzzle challenges - I like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it in 8 moves, here's my [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gACcm.jpg). I didn't mark squares as lonely, since all white ones are lonely and I did it in paint. Also I didn't give a turn direction but it should be obvious.

Comment: Great! From what I am aware, this is logically the best solution

Comment: Great work.  Better than mine (I was at 10).  Seeing yours it makes me feel like I over-complicated things for myself.

Comment: Great work! If possible it would be great if you could add the images to your answer here instead of just a link.

Answer (score 3):

**10 Moves**
So as I disobyed the very first rule, this time i worked with 2x2 square blocks instead of 1x2 or 2x1 blocks as per specified rules by the OP. As for any other rule violations, i'm sorry if I did, but here is my solution:

> [image: Solution]

**OLD ANSWER**
**<del>9 Moves</del>**

> I tried this puzzle for the first time, so I hope I followed the previous rules OP has posted. I went for 1x2 and 2x1 rotations so I hope that such rotations are allowed. Also, if i understood correctly, you cannot replace a double square block by itself, but you can replace it using other double square blocks. So this solution, I went for 5x5 blocks not 7x7.
> My Solution:
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob41Q.png
>
> Please tell if I disobeyed any rule, but hopefully not.

Comment: Yea, you've violated the 1st basic rule. You can **only select an area of squares that is itself a square**. Hopefully that is more clear, it looks like you've understood everything else though

Comment: Your answer is now valid. However it can be done in less moves!

Comment: @Adam Pelican did it in 8 moves, is it possible in less?

Comment: It shouldn't be possible in less moves